# How can I push a number into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, numbers

I've been trying to push a number after the "for loop" into "x" but I cant use "x += count.push()" because it's not an array.

```
function partsSums(ls) {

   let count = 0;
   let x = []

   while (ls.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {

         count += ls[i]
      }
      x += count;
      count = 0;
      ls.shift()
   }
   return x;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

I need to get x = [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0] and I'm getting 2020191610 instead.
 I'm pretty sure this is a no-brainer but I seem to be missing something...

Comment: It would be x.push(value) not count.push() if you are trying to append to the array stored in x

Comment: damm easy... off course... thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce from the right.

```js
function partsSums(array) {
    return array.reduceRight((r, v) => [v + r[0], ...r], [0]);
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Comment: ok, I didn't know this method... I need to take a look at this...